# How to find the sum of all values for a key using Apache Spark having ((key1,value),(key2,value)) pattern

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am having a dataset as following-

```
A  B  C
(a,c,30)
(a,b,20)
(b,c,10)
(c,d,1)
```

Now I need to process the above data to get output like -
Any key in column A will get multiplied by 2 times of C
and any Key in Column B will get multiplied by 3 times of C

So the expected output here will be -

```
a   100      =30*2+20*2
b   80       =20*3+10*2
c   122      =30*3+10*3+1*2
d   3        =1*3
```

I could manage to write like following-

```
val x = sc.parallelize(List(
  ("a","b",20),
  ("b","c",10),
  ("a","c",30),
  ("c","d",1)
))

val myVal = x.map({
  case (a,b,c) => ((a-> 2 * c), (b -> 3 * c))
})

myVal.foreach(println)
```

output-

```
((a,60),(c,90))
((c,2),(d,3))
((a,40),(b,60))
((b,20),(c,30))
```

After that I am not able to break it further
How can I get the result expected using spark scala ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is to make it flat first - associate one value with one key. Then it'd be possible to use reduceByKey operation to sum it up.

I'm not scala developer, but something like this would probably work.

```
myVal
  .flatMap({ case (a, b, c) => List(a -> 2 * c, b -> 3 * c) })
  .reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
  .foreach(println(_))
```

List here is an additional object that has to be created each time and it might be better to avoid it. So, something like this might work - look through the data twice, but cache it before.

```
myVal.cache()
  .map({ case (a, b, c) => a -> 2 * c })
  .union(rdd.map({ case (a, b, c) => b -> 3 * c }))
  .reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
  .foreach(println(_))
myVal.unpersist()
```